# What is difference between "has been taken residency" and "has been taking residency"?

Tags: meaning, present-perfect, legalese, progressive-aspect, perfect-constructions

Which one is correct, or if both, what is difference between "has been taken residency" and "has been taking residency"?

EDIT: few more details about the question

I write this phrase in "proof of address" letter for tenants living in my house. I am based in United Kingdom.

Full sentence:

> This is to confirm that John Doe has been taking residency at the
>   property since XXX.

Comment: Some AmE speakers may be happy to use *take residency* in the context of *a medical graduate who has completed an internship and is engaged in further, often specialized, training in a hospital department* (definition from OED). But that's a highly specialised usage which [doesn't even occur often enough to graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+took+residence%2Che+took+residency&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20took%20residence%3B%2Cc0) in NGrams. Normally you *take [up] **residence*** when you start living somewhere.

Comment: Martin: I don't think this question can be properly answered until you clarify the context. Note that *has been **taken** residency* is syntactically invalid, and *has been **taking** residency* is semantically problematic (for the same reason as you can't really say *I have been taking citizenship* - it's a one-off action, not a continuous state of affairs). But it may well make a difference whether you mean *residence* in the sense of the hospital position a junior doctor can take [up], or the more general sense of *residing, living* somewhere.

Comment: Oh dear,  I had no idea **residency** has that many meanings... Please see edited question, I added more details.

Comment: Martin: I suggest you don't want any form of ***take*** at all. You could say *John Doe has been resident at the property since XXX*, but it's a bit "stuffy". I'd just say *John Doe has resided at the property since XXX* (or more likely, *has **lived***). When in doubt, stick to the simpler forms.

Comment: Papa has been a rollling stone, wherever he has been laying his hat he has been taking residency.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your edited question:

Either the present perfect or present perfect continuous are fine, but in a more idiomatic usage:

> This is to confirm that...

and then

> ...John Doe has resided/lived at the property since xxx.

or

> ...John Doe has been residing/living at the property since XXX.

With *since* both tenses indicate that the stated action started in the past and continues to the moment of writing.

The difference between the two tenses with *since* is subtle and not worth worrying about, as they do no affect your purpose.

To wit: the continuous simply *stretches out* the act of *living* (or *residing*)  rather than presenting it as a punctiliar event. However, the continuous also is used very often to present a situation that is of limited duration and may soon change.

> He's been living here since 2013 but he'll be moving next year.

But again, in your context and purpose, either tense is fine, although I prefer the present perfect (non continuous).

Answer (score 0):

Correct grammar would be:

> has taken residency

-or-

> has been taking residency

In your example residency is the thing which *has been taken*, so you could say "residency has been taken", but this would sound unnatural to a native speaker in most scenarios.

Comment: As a BrE speaker I'm not very familiar with the (primarily AmE) usage *resident physician*, but it seems unlikely to me many speakers would use the *continuous* form of the verb to reference it. To me, *He has been taking residency* is akin to *He has been taking the job*. Which doesn't really make sense, since *taking residency* is like *accepting a job* - you either do it or you don't; you can *keep* doing it.

Comment: **OH!** I didn't even *think* about doctors! I was purely thinking about national residency, as in "he has been taking residency in Germany". For doctors, I think "he did his residency" would actually be the more common usage.

Comment: I've been circumspect about OP's usage because *taking [up] residency* in the hospital job sense is essentially an AmE usage. But I think I can confidently say *He has been taking residency in Germany* is completely unidiomatic for the sense of *He has been **living in** Germany*. You can't do that "continuously", so if you want to use a word based on *reside = live, dwell*, it would have to be the one-off action *He took [up] residence in Germany*.

Comment: Fair, in which case "he has been resident in Germany" would probably be preferable to "he has been taking residency in Germany".

Comment: Well, we'd need to ask a US doctor whether *He took [up] residence/residency at our local hospital* could validly be used for the specialised *period of training [in a hosptital]* sense. In which case it's at least *feasible* you could use the continuous form of the verb in that context (though it sounds "odd" to me as a non-medical non-AmE speaker). But apparently OP is asking about the more general sense, where it's not just "preferable" to avoid the continuous - I'd say it's logically/syntactically *unacceptable* to use it.